# SEO, ordering and duplication of content

Tags: seo, canonical-link

I run a specialized news site and am trying to apply a little bit of SEO sauce to it. One of the most important things I hear is to avoid duplication of content. I've covered all the basics but I'm stuck with ordering of content.

As an example, the archive of the site is orderable by date, views, and rating. Since we don't have that many news items, an archive page for a particular day has usually only a couple of items, so the following URLs all have the same content, albeit in different ordering:

- /news/archive/2010/05/16/
- /news/archive/2010/05/16/?o=views
- /news/archive/2010/05/16/?o=rating

Do search machines penalize this particular kind of duplication of content? And if yes, what's the best way to avoid said penalty? `<link rel="canonical" />`? Tell Google & Co. to ingore the `o` parameter? Marking the ordering links with `nofollow`? Only allow the indexation of the date-ordered archive sites through robots.txt (not sure if this is even possible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you have a dynamic URL which is in
>   the standard format like
>   foo?key1=value&key2=value2 we
>   recommend that you leave the url
>   unchanged, and Google will determine
>   which parameters can be removed

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/09/dynamic-urls-vs-static-urls.html

Basically, Google doesn't care about that. Googlebot is smart enough to handle this issue for you.

I always use a canonical tag, seems cleaner to me.

Comment: In my experience, googlebot isn't smart enough to figure this out on its own.  I should give it hints like rel=canonical or telling it about the parameter in webmaster tools as other answers suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it affects search engine rankings or not (probably does). You can tell in Google Webmaster which query string parameters to ignore (see Site Configuration/Settings). You can also add this to robots.txt:

```
User-agent: *
/news/archive/*/*/*/?*o=
```

This is block the crawler even if you have other query parameters, as in

```
/news/archive/2010/05/16/?direction=asc&o=date
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to Google Webmaster Tools > Configuration > URL Parameters and setup your "o" parameter as one that sorts content.